# pre_commit_hook: add directory to commit

Tags: git, github, pre-commit-hook

I manage multiple projects in the same github repository. I need a way I can add the name of the directory to commit where changes were made. For example:

My repository has 4 projects:

```
/a
/b
/c
/d
```

and I make changes to d. I want the commit to be `[d] commit message`. I understand that we can add the branch to commit easily, I need help with adding the directory containing the staged changes.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have changes in all directories? Would you then want to add all affected directory names to the commit message?

Comment: No, that will be a special case. this usually never happens as these are different project in same repo, we work on a single project per branch.